# How to access php SESSION variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to create an image uploading website. In this, when a user logs in, I set a `$_SESSION['id']` variable in php. Now, I wish to check if `$_SESSION['id']` is set in my javascript file (general.js) in order to carry out certain functions. How should I go about doing it?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
<?php $session_value=(isset($_SESSION['id']))?$_SESSION['id']:''; ?>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var myvar='<?php echo $session_value;?>';
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="general.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
    </html>
```

In above code snippet I have initialized global variable **myvar**  with value stored into php session variable into script file before **general.js** file is referenced in script.It will be accessible in **general.js** file

Comment: I'm not able to access myvar in general.js

Comment: So the problem now is, if $_SESSION['id'] is set, then the code in general.js works fine...if it is not set, then my console shows the error "unterminated string literal" ..what's going wrong?

Comment: @eagleAtlantis Please find modified code snippet in above answer

Comment: Those answers are terrible since you usualy put js in separate file. A legit solution woud be to set a <input type="hidden" id="session_something" style="display:none" value="desired_value"> and to get is with $('#id) or document.getElementbyId.value

Comment: @Dice What do you mean by "usually put js in separate file"? You still can, only that one line needs to be in `<script>`

Comment: This is super useful, thank you so much!

Comment: how do you debug a php code embedded inside JS?  This really looks odd to me.  I am sure there is more elegant answer.  Look at the syntax.  Why no terminating semicolon.  There is something very inconsistent with this answer.

Comment: @Nguaia, I think you are getting yourself confused with HTML tags and PHP tags. Give it a quick google. (y)

Answer (score 8):

A simple example please try this

```
<?php 
session_start();
$_SESSION['id'] = 12;

?>

<script>
alert(<?php echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>);
</script>
```

You can even use php variable and array as variable in js like below

```
<?php
    $id= $_SESSION['id'];
    $data= array('one', 'two', 'three');
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var idr = '<?php echo $id; ?>';
    var datar = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;
</script>
```

Comment: If I put <?php session_start(); ?> in the beginning of my general.js, everything stops working..what should I do?

Comment: @meagler Why would you be putting that in a .js file to begin with? Both of these are .html

Comment: Left something very important piece of information.  The extension of this file must be .php not .html.  If this file is kept with .html extension, this will not work.

Comment: I don't want to sound rude, but the occurrence of `<?php` has already emphasised that it has to be a PHP file. Although, there are also ways to keep your file extension `.html`, and this still works. But that's totally a different topic.

Comment: @AliYousuf - Sorry.  You are right. I came across html extension and php extension code with this kind of hybrid code.  So I just want to emphasize the importance of the extension.

Answer (score 5):

Here PHP is server-Side execution and JavaScript is Client side execution. and `$_SESSION` is a server-side construct.So probably you can not access that directly using JavaScript You would need to store that variable in `$_COOKIE` to be able to access it client-side.

You can get that Session using PHP, and then use that for the JavaScript like this

```
<?php
$variablephp = $_SESSION['category'];
?>

<script>
var variablejs = "<?php echo $variablephp; ?>" ;
alert("category = " + variablejs);
</script>
```

Here you are getting Session like `echo $variablephp` using PHP, and the assign that value to JavaScript variable.

Comment: I think another option is saving the session inside text and read the text 
using document.getElementById("text_variable_name").value;

Comment: you don't need double quotes around if the variable is a number.

Comment: @Nguaial, I have already answered that for you in answers below :)

Comment: We can access _SESSION from javascript by writing the code as said. Saying that we can not access the _SESSION variable because php is server side and javascript is client side is very misleading. Yes, javascript is clientside but if the <script></script> is included within the .php file, the <?php ?> code within the javascript script will be executed.

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to `echo` the session ID in a javascript variable.

```
<script>
  var sessionId = "<?php echo $_SESSION['id']; ?>";

  // Your javascript code goes here
</script>
```

Comment: there is no need to put double quotes if the value is a numerical value.

Comment: You never apply calculation on `sessionId`.. It wouldn't matter if it's a numerical value or string. So quote caters both cases.

Comment: I am getting this: JavaScript Error Handling: Unexpected Token: <. Running this is Chrome.

Comment: It is not supposed to be run in any browser directly. It's meant to be served by PHP server, which in turn fill up the `<?php ... ?>` segment.