# Javascript Use of PHP Echo

Tags: javascript, php

Using this [StackOverflow Question/Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41391862/how-to-access-php-session-variable-in-javascript), I have a Tooltip Javascript that is supposed to use a PHP echo of a session variable.  Instead of actually writing out the value, it is writing out the variable name, myvar?

I tried to \ the echo statement where ' occur with no luck.

Here is the code in question and screenshot of what I'm getting on mouseover:

```
var ddimgtooltip={

    tiparray:function(){
        var tooltips=[]
        var myvar='<?php echo($row_WADAHTG_ScheduleRequest[\'EmNo\']); ?>';
        tooltips[0]=["image/emp/$myvar.bmp", "$myvar", {background:"#DDECFF", width:"200px"}]
        return tooltips //do not remove/change this line
    }(),
```

[image]

Comment: echo it, just like the line above it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I do string interpolation in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408289/how-can-i-do-string-interpolation-in-javascript)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try tho change this:

```
var myvar='<?php echo($row_WADAHTG_ScheduleRequest[\'EmNo\']); ?>';
tooltips[0]=["image/emp/$myvar.bmp", "$myvar", {background:"#DDECFF", width:"200px"}]
```

to this:

```
var myvar='<?php echo($row_WADAHTG_ScheduleRequest[\'EmNo\']); ?>';
tooltips[0]=["image/emp/" + myvar + ".bmp", myvar, {background:"#DDECFF", width:"200px"}]
```

you have already your php value into `myvar` so you don't need to use `$myvar` as in php but only `myvar` for javascript

Comment: yep... he is mixing php and js

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
var myvar='<?php echo($row_WADAHTG_ScheduleRequest[\'EmNo\']); ?>';
tooltips[0]=["image/emp/" + myvar + ".bmp", myvar, {background:"#DDECFF", width:"200px"}]
```